# ag grid scroll bar is not showing when column length is high

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid to display my table values, i have like more than 15 columns which is not fitting to the screen, so i would like to enable scroll for the same. Currently its hiding after 5 or 6 columns. Please let me know how to enable scroll for the same. What is the property to enable scroll in ag-grid ?

```
<div>
    <div id="myGrid" ag-grid="vm.taskColumnOptions"  style="height:300px; padding: 10px;" class="ag-blue"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about horizontal scroll? If so that is on by default and if your application isn't showing horizontal scroll then please recreate the issue using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/) so that we can help you debug